# xCode9.2 | GoogleMaps 2.6 - Failed to load optimized model at path

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps

I know this has been asked hundreds of time specially with 2.5, but I am unable to obtain the reverse and not sure what's next in the resolution path if any.

Googoled and Stackled here no luck.

App is not crashing, just not giving me the reverse and printing out 3 times the below:

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/34161A32-68A6-483E-B582-DA1DE57F4548/xxx.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
```

I have tried with GoogleMaps 2.2,2.5 and 2.6

I have not implemented any map just "import GoogleMaps" and the few lines below:

```
                    let test = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(53.349546666666669,-3.2382383333333333)
                    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
                    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(test) { response , error in
                        if let address = response?.firstResult() {
                            print(address) }
```

Query done in the web browser using my API works ok. Maybe it's my REVERSED_CLIENT_ID wrong?

Am I missing something? If not, is this a bug? If yes, any workaround? If not, what's the next step through the resolution?

Thanks a mil.

Comment: Sounds like the following bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64504919

Comment: That's odd. Any workaround?